# RewriteCond regexp not taking images

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Having the following code I cant configurate .htaccess. It takes .js and .css files, but not takes .png images

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(.*)/\.(jpg|css|js|gif|png)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$  index.php?$1=$2
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$  index.php?$1=$2&$3=$4
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$  index.php?$1=$2&$3=$4&$5=$6
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RewriteCond conditions **only** get applied to the immediately following RewriteRule, so those conditions you have only get applied to the first rule. You need to duplicate them for the other 2 rules if you want them to be applied to those as well:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(.*)/\.(jpg|css|js|gif|png)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$  index.php?$1=$2

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(.*)/\.(jpg|css|js|gif|png)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$  index.php?$1=$2&$3=$4

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(.*)/\.(jpg|css|js|gif|png)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$  index.php?$1=$2&$3=$4&$5=$6
```